# Append columns to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I set up a four column zeros array:

```
X_large = np.zeros((X.shape[0], 4)
```

And I have an array X as below:

```
X = np.array([
[0, 1]
[2, 2]
[3, 4]
[6, 5]
])
```

How can I get X_large to take X and have the last two columns show the first value of each row of the array squared and the second value of each row of the array cubed?  Meaning:

```
X_large = [ [0, 1, 0, 1],
            [2, 2, 4, 8],
            [3, 4, 9, 64],
            [6, 5, 36, 125] ]
```

This is probably not too hard, but I'm a pretty novice programmer in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the power of `X` first, then do the `column_stack`:

```
np.column_stack((X, X ** [2,3]))
#array([[  0,   1,   0,   1],
#       [  2,   2,   4,   8],
#       [  3,   4,   9,  64],
#       [  6,   5,  36, 125]])
```

Or use `np.power` for the power calculation:

```
np.column_stack((X, np.power(X, [2,3])))
#array([[  0,   1,   0,   1],
#       [  2,   2,   4,   8],
#       [  3,   4,   9,  64],
#       [  6,   5,  36, 125]])
```